# What is the purpose of writing functions and methods? When should you make a snippet of code into a function or method?

Tags: object-oriented, programming-practices

I have a philosophical disagreement with one of my co-workers, and I'm trying to get back to basics here. What is the purpose of a method?

In this question, consider this example. I was criticized for writing the following two methods. I would like to give the caveat that this is a boiled down baby-example, that there were other places in my code that were more complicated but similar.

## The baby example

```
class UI:
    def __init___(self):
        self.thingsCheckBox = # checkbox widget
        self.moreThingsCheckBox = # checkbox widget

def wantShowThings(self):
    return self.thingsCheckBox.checkState()

def wantShowMoreThings(self):
    return self.moreThingsCheckBox.checkState()
```

So, my co-worker questioned me about writing those two methods. Ultimately, I was forced to remove those two methods (as they did not pass his code review). And this ultimately meant...

## My version

```
if ui.wantShowThings():
    # do stuff...

if ui.wantShowMoreThings():
    # do more stuff...
```

## His version (that ultimately won)

```
 if ui.thingsCheckBox.checkState():
     # ...

 if ui.moreThingsCheckBox.checkState():
    # ...
```

What is the purpose of writing those methods?

- reuse: I think we all agree about reusability. If a bit of code is being copy and pasted multiple times, it should be put into a function or method so that if the code ever changes, you only have to change it in one place. My co worker argues that reusability is the *only* reason to write something into a function.  My co-worker said that if a function isn't called more than once, I should "inline" the logic (write it in the place its used) and write a comment. "Short" methods are "useless" and serve to increase the "spaghetti code". "Stop making me jump around to figure out the logic".

I believe that writing functions serves other purposes:

- encapsulation: Hide the implementation of your class. This brings your thinking into a higher level and abstracts away the concrete parts of your code. In my above example, it doesn't matter with wantShowThings() whether or not the underlying implementation is a checkbox, radio button, or even a server call. We're thinking more abstractly than a checkbox. We're thinking "if we want to show things".
- documentation: I think code itself can serve as documentation. I know there are pretty radical people that think that comments are completely useless. While I'm not quite as extreme, I sympathize with the philosophy. Why write a comment when you can refactor it into a method with a meaningful name? In my example, I don't need a comment `# This returns true if we want to show things`, it's in the method name.

I believe that I have a multitude of literature that supports my thinking. "Clean Code", CodingHorror. I took a class with Stanford's David Cheriton that certainly stood on my side as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When is it appropriate to make a separate function when there will only ever be a single call to said function?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/308108/when-is-it-appropriate-to-make-a-separate-function-when-there-will-only-ever-be)

Comment: I think your question may be addressed in http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/107669/one-line-functions-that-are-called-only-once - Addresses your co-workers comments about inline logic.

Comment: Personally for this simple use case, I prefer your coworkers code. As someone that has to maintain a very large code base, it drives me crazy to track down a method like "CanDoX" only to figure out it returns X... in my eyes there is no point in creating a method to get the value of X if X is clearly defined, as in your case of `CheckBox.State`. Keep your code simple until you reach the point that it is hard to read or repeated, then you can look to refactor it into another method.

Comment: @Rachel: as someone that has to maintain a very large code base, too, it drives me crazy when devs pick version 1 and use method name which only describes what the method does 60% correctly. However, when the function name is picked wisely, version 1 is IMHO clearly preferrable.

Comment: The answer to this question is actually very opinion based. If you worked in my team, you'd be encouraged to use your, the first, version as opposed to Rachel's team, who in this case prefers the second approach.

Comment: @DocBrown I am in support of a new "CanDoX" method when you have to query it multiple times from multiple places, however I was specifically referencing methods which are only called by one line of code. Perhaps I should have clarified in that comment :)

Comment: @Rachel: well, my point is that reuse is not the only motivation for building methods, and that in a code review I would not do such nonsense like insisting to replace a well-named single-liner by a less readable "control-name.checkState" construct. However, I also would not insist to refactor any "control-name.checkState" immediately to a single method, if the first one is readable enough and only used in one place. Both variants are IMHO tolerable.

Comment: If performance is not an issue I claim it doesn't matter if the method is called in one place or a hundred. If named appropriately and if it performs one task only and not some arbitrary combination of tasks, wrapping things up in a method makes your code read like a story which makes it more accessible and flexible. As a programmer reading the code you first want to know what it does, not how. In this particular case it is also isolating the UI from the logic, an extra boon.

Answer (score 5):

The main purpose of a method (besides reuse) is

**Building a useful abstraction** by introducing a carefully chosen, meaningful name.

(You called that "encapsulation" and "documentation", both not wrong, but not fully the term which fits IMHO best to it).

Maybe you can convince you coworker by telling him that his version clearly violates the "[Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)". Or maybe just tell him I  think his version is mediocre, yours is definitely better (as long as the function name really does make the purpose clearer) ;-)

Comment: As Knuth said, "Name and conquer".  Once you have names for "trivial" things you will find nontrivial ways to reuse them.

Comment: Related:  http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html ;-)

Answer (score 4):

> My co-worker said that if a function isn't called more than once, I should "inline" the logic (write it in the place its used) and write a comment. "Short" methods are "useless" and serve to increase the "spaghetti code". "Stop making me jump around to figure out the logic".

And on the other hand:

> I believe that writing functions serves other purposes:
>
> Encapsulation...
>
> Documentation...

And in the end, you are both right. Your coworker is right that making a method that just obscures a line of code called once can be obfuscating, and provides no value. You are right that a well made function can clarify what is going on as well as create an abstraction so that implementation details can be changed freely.

Which is better falls squarely into "it depends" territory. Not just on what is being abstracted, but how it is used, how it will be used, the skill of your programmers, the obscureness of the domain... dozens of things. You weigh the benefits/disadvantages of one option versus the other and make your best guess based on the knowledge available to you.

Sometimes you will guess wrong, and you get to refactor. That is part and parcel of the art of programming.

Answer (score 1):

I think you already answered your question. I had the same thinking while I was beginning to develop for Android. I had this member variable in my `CheatActivity` class

```
public static final String EXTRA_ANSWER_SHOWN = "com.sabernova.geoquiz.answer_shown";
```

...and this method as well:

```
public static boolean wasAnswerShown(Intent data) {
    return data.getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_SHOWN, false);
}
```

The data object was received in the `QuizActivity` class which is also the launcher for my app and I didn't understand why the author wanted to include a method and the string tag for the `Boolean` extra in the second activity. Why not directly access it?

There were two things:

1. The `Boolean` extra is created and thus belongs within `CheatActivity` and hence, it's tag should also reside within `CheatActivity` -- encapsulating data.
2. Say I used the statement just once. Doesn't mean it will always be like that. I will expand my app in the future and that means I might use it more than once. Or say I change the string tag in the `CheatActivity` class. Now, I have to go ahead and change all the sightings of the string inside `QuizActivity` as well. This will be hectic in the long run and could've been solved by putting the right statement inside a well-named function -- Reuse.

So, in a nutshell, creating the right functions means that **any change in the actual code would not break up the entire system and cause a lot of rewriting code** since the function serves as the interface through which, we can execute code and get the needed stuff.